# XSLT How to get total Number of occurrences of an element of multiple parents

Tags: xslt, count, xslt-2.0

I have a XML need to get the count of occurrences of an element

```
<lines>
<line>
 <accountings>
  <accounting>
    <account>
      <seg1>value1</seg2>
    </account>
  </accounting>
  <accounting>
    <account>
      <seg1>value2</seg2>
    </account>
  </accounting>
 </accountings>
 </line>
 <line>
<accountings>
 <accounting>
    <account>
      <seg1>value3</seg2>
    </account>
  </accounting>
  </accountings>
 </line>
 <line>
 <account>
    <seg1>value4</seg1>
 </account>
 </line>
</lines>
```

In the Above xml there are total 4 `<account>` elements

I need the output as 4, but whenever I try for-each or for-each-group and count on each iterate I get value as 1111, atleast I need a way to add all the counts.

Comment: You could get a better answer in context if you included your existing XSLT and show where and why you need the total count.  Your mentioning of for-each and for-each-group indicates you may be trying to use XSLT as an imperative language, which it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for looping or grouping, just use

```
count(//account)
```

Comment: Thank You. This solves it. Being new to XSLT, My mind is trying to solve it as imperative language problem.

Comment: XSLT is declarative and functional (no mutable "variables").  The input XML drives the process, not the stylesheet.  What I found useful for learning this was Evan Lenz's [XSLT 1.0 Pocket Reference](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100087.do). It contains a succinct and beautifully written description of how XSLT works.  It's kind of out of date now, but worth it if it can set right your mental model, as it did for me many (12) years ago.